# how to achieve blurry parallax background

Tags: css

My objective is to have a full-screen parallax background that is blurred.

The problem is that when you blur an element it no longer spans the full size of the container (because the edges are blurry). I found an example that suggested using transform:scale in order to stretch it just a little bigger than the size required for 'cover', although now this now makes it so that when you scroll down the page the background slowly moves down as well (once again exposing the blurred edges).

HTML

```
<div class="viewport"></div>
```

CSS

```
.viewport {
    background-image: url("images/img1.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    filter: blur(7px);
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 130vh;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting the `viewport` in a `viewport-wrapper` with hidden overflow?

HTML

```
<div class="viewport-wrapper"><div class="viewport"></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.viewport-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/upccjesse/pen/jXOqQx)

Comment: yeah I tried doing that, but left it out of the post because it didn't end up doing making a difference. The 'cover' just seems to take into account the internal div ignoring the wrapper, until you transform:scale it and then we end up with the sliding effect I described.